# html alert keeps redirecting my page to index.html, I want it to just show a alert

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my decline button just pop-up an alert, right now it shows the alert then redirects my page to `index.php`.

The `index.php` is included in my form `action="index.php"`.

Note: This is a .php file.

Sorry if it's a trivial question, I'm new and still learning.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Meta Data -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Privacy.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="Privacy page">
      <meta name="author" content="groupdev17">
      <!-- Title Data -->
      <title>Privacy Policy</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- PHP including connection,header, and nav bar -->
      <?php
         include('connection.php');
         include("header.html");
         include("navBar.php");
         ?>
      <!-- class made for contents of privacy statement -->
      <div class="privacyDisplay">
         <p>
         <div class="main-content">
            <h2 id="h2TITLE">PRIVACY STATEMENT</h2>
            <br></br>
            Your privacy is important to us. This privacy statement explains the personal data that we collect and store, how we processes it, and for what purposes. In order for you to add products to a cart and to purchase products from us, we collect and store the following personal information on you:
            <br></br>
            <b>1) Name:</b><br>
            <b>2) Email:</b><br>
            <b>3) Home address:</b><br></br>
            When you complete your purchase by checking out we then collect, but do not store, the following additional information:
            Credit card information
            At no time do we give access to your personal information to third parties.
            In order to continue to use our web site, you must select Accept to indicate that you understand and accept how your personal information is being collected and stored. If you select Decline, then your account will be deactivated and your personal information will no longer be available to anyone. You may still reactivate your account at any time by accepting these terms at a later time. 
            </p>
            <!-- buttons to accept or decline privacy -->
            <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input name = "answer" type="submit" value="Accept" onclick="acceptFunction()" id="privacyAccept">
            <input name = "answer" type="submit" value="Decline" onclick="declineFunction()" id="privacyDecline">
</form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- copywrite -->
      <div class="container">
         <footer>Victoria Mobile © 2019</footer>
      </div>
      <!-- including footer -->
      <?php
         include("footer.html")
         ?>
      <!-- javascript methods for accept and decline -->
      <script>
         function acceptFunction(){
         
               }
         
         function declineFunction(){
          alert("You must accept the policy agreement to continue");
  return false;

         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good question, I think that this is one that gets most all developers at some time during their career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button submits the form so you need to stop that by returning the `false` to the button's click handler or change the button's type from submit to button.

```js
function declineFunction() {
  alert("You must accept the policy agreement to continue");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input name="answer" type="submit" value="Decline" onclick="return declineFunction()" id="privacyDecline">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you mean `<input name="answer" type="button"` in your snippet.

Comment: @glhr No actually I don't, but you see in my answer that I offer that as an alternative.

Comment: my bad. I thought the HTML part of the snippet was meant to illustrate the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `type="submit"` from the `Decline` button. Use `type="button"`  instead:

```
<input name="answer" type="button" value="Decline" onclick="declineFunction()" id="privacyDecline">
```

Comment: Done you got the answer, so simple and easy. Thanks G

Comment: @Karanvir1 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to submit your form, use a button instead of an input with type of submit. This way the button will do the action that you associate with it rather than submitting the form.

```html
<button type="button" value="Decline" onclick="declineFunction()" id="privacyDecline">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `preventDefault`

```js
function declineFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("You must accept the policy agreement to continue");
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input onclick="declineFunction(event)" name="answer" type="submit" value="Decline"  id="privacyDecline">
</form>
```